# aregImpute function in R package Hmisc

Tags: r, hmisc, mi

I am a novice and I am confused about whether aregImpute draws a new bootstrap sample from the original data prior to each time it creates one of the "n.impute" multiply imputed datasets?

I know that I need to capture the variability in the original sampling distribution and I am not sure if aregImpute is resampling the original distribution with replacement (e.g. doing a bootstrap prior to doing imputations).

If I need to capture that variability, then do I need to use a function like **boot** from the **boot** package to pass the bootstrap resample datasets to aregImpute?

Thanks!

Comment: It appears you are asking us to read the help page for you, which reads:  "`aregImpute` takes all aspects of uncertainty in the imputations into account by using the bootstrap to approximate the process of drawing predicted values from a full Bayesian predictive distribution. Different bootstrap resamples are used for each of the multiple imputations..." You should, instead, have shown us which part of this you are having trouble with and what parts of the example code was giving you difficulties. Or shown us  the code you didn't understand. (Bootstraps usually are done with replacement.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I read the function description in Hmisc.pdf and the blurb in the Regression Modeling Strategies book before posting my question. I also contrived a dataset that I could easily tell if resampling with replacement of the original dataset was happening. I extracted a completed dataset after running aregImpute and compared it to the oiginal. MI is occurring, but resampling the original dataset with replacement does not seem to be happening prior to each round of MI. I hoped someone familiar with the aregImpute function would comment.

Comment: Well, for one thing all that extra information would have been appropriate in the question body. For another thing, I would be hugely surprised if Frank Harrell were doing bootstraps without replacement. "Sampling with replacement" is practically in the definition of "bootstrap". The only instance I found in a cursory glance at the code showed that the instance of a `sample` did have a logical argument given to the replacement argument. It looked like the answer is sometimes 'yes' and sometimes 'no' but whether the "no' applies to your situation is impossible to determine, ... no specifics.